# Grouping with no relation

Tags: xslt-1.0

Xml:

```
<items>
    <transaction>
        <header>
            <col1>H</col1>
            <col2>XXXX</col2>
            <col3>YYY12345</col3>
            <col4/>
            <col5>YYY12345A1234</col5>
        </header>
    </transaction>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>1</col2>
        <col3>5358478</col3>
        <col4>-1.0000</col4>
        <col5>CA</col5>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>2</col2>
        <col3>9477498</col3>
        <col4>1.0000</col4>
        <col5>CA</col5>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>2</col2>
        <col3>9477498</col3>
        <col4>1.0000</col4>
        <col5>CA</col5>
    </item>
    <transaction>
        <header>
            <col1>H</col1>
            <col2>XXXX</col2>
            <col3>YYY12345</col3>
            <col4/>
            <col5>YYY12345A1236</col5>
        </header>
    </transaction>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>1</col2>
        <col3>1676600</col3>
        <col4>1.0000</col4>
        <col5>CA</col5>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>2</col2>
        <col3>5602891</col3>
        <col4>1.0000</col4>
        <col5>CA</col5>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>3</col2>
        <col3>7990401</col3>
        <col4>2.0000</col4>
        <col5>CA</col5>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>4</col2>
        <col3>6985683</col3>
        <col4>1.0000</col4>
        <col5>CA</col5>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>5</col2>
        <col3>9477498</col3>
        <col4>-1.0000</col4>
        <col5>CA</col5>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>D</col1>
        <col2>5</col2>
        <col3>9477498</col3>
        <col4>-1.0000</col4>
        <col5>CA</col5>
    </item>
</items>
```

Desired output:

```
<items>
    <transaction>
        <header>
            <col1>H</col1>
            <col2>XXXX</col2>
            <col3>YYY12345</col3>
            <col4/>
            <col5>YYY12345A1234</col5>
        </header>
        <item>
            <col1>D</col1>
            <col2>1</col2>
            <col3>5358478</col3>
            <col4>-1.0000</col4>
            <col5>CA</col5>
        </item>
        <item>
            <col1>D</col1>
            <col2>2</col2>
            <col3>9477498</col3>
            <col4>1.0000</col4>
            <col5>CA</col5>
        </item>
        <item>
            <col1>D</col1>
            <col2>2</col2>
            <col3>9477498</col3>
            <col4>1.0000</col4>
            <col5>CA</col5>
        </item>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <header>
            <col1>H</col1>
            <col2>XXXX</col2>
            <col3>YYY12345</col3>
            <col4/>
            <col5>YYY12345A1236</col5>
        </header>
        <item>
            <col1>D</col1>
            <col2>1</col2>
            <col3>1676600</col3>
            <col4>1.0000</col4>
            <col5>CA</col5>
        </item>
        <item>
            <col1>D</col1>
            <col2>2</col2>
            <col3>5602891</col3>
            <col4>1.0000</col4>
            <col5>CA</col5>
        </item>
        <item>
            <col1>D</col1>
            <col2>3</col2>
            <col3>7990401</col3>
            <col4>2.0000</col4>
            <col5>CA</col5>
        </item>
        <item>
            <col1>D</col1>
            <col2>4</col2>
            <col3>6985683</col3>
            <col4>1.0000</col4>
            <col5>CA</col5>
        </item>
        <item>
            <col1>D</col1>
            <col2>5</col2>
            <col3>9477498</col3>
            <col4>-1.0000</col4>
            <col5>CA</col5>
        </item>
        <item>
            <col1>D</col1>
            <col2>5</col2>
            <col3>9477498</col3>
            <col4>-1.0000</col4>
            <col5>CA</col5>
        </item>
    </transaction>
</items>
```

I am trying to do it in xslt 1.0. I'm having hard time figuring out how to move those item elements inside the transaction block.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a few minutes reformatting your sample input and output and using diff, I think what you are trying to do is just move all the siblings of a `transaction` element into the transaction element as new children.  True?

Adding the following templates to your stylesheet produces a stylesheet which produces the desired output.

First, the template for `items` calls apply-templates *only* for its transaction children (since they are the only ones whose output should appear as children of the output `items` element):

```
<xsl:template match="items">
  <items>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="transaction"/>
  </items>
</xsl:template>
```

The template for `transaction` calls apply-templates first for its children, in the default mode.  (This handles the `header` element.)  Then it calls apply-templates on its immediate right sibling (which will become the first `item` child of the `transaction` element in the output), in a special mode (here called `items`).

```
<xsl:template match="transaction">
  <transaction>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:apply-templates 
        mode="items" 
        select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
  </transaction>
</xsl:template>
```

The `items` mode is specialized for collecting the items of a given transaction.  It exploits the fact that the items are all siblings, all are copied verbatim to the output, and the sequence of items ends when the next `transaction` sibling is found.

So the template for `item` in the `items` mode does two things:  first it copies itself, then it applies templates, still in `items` mode, to its immediate right sibling.  If that's another item, we will end up evaluating this template again.  And again.  And so on.  (If you have extremely numerous items and a weak XSLT optimizer, requirements for stack memory may climb.)

```
<xsl:template match="item" mode="items">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  <xsl:apply-templates 
      mode="items" 
      select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Eventually, the immediate right sibling of an `item` element is going to be a `transaction` element.  At that point, we want the recursion to stop, so the `items`-mode template for `transaction` does nothing.  (It doesn't need to handle the transaction, because the default-mode template for transaction will do so.)

```
<xsl:template match="transaction" mode="items"/>
```

The right-sibling-recursion pattern is worth learning; it makes grouping tasks like this one simple.

Comment: This is awesome. Although I had to do it in the code since I was running out of time the idea is great, I'll use it in the future.