# How to Use Break condition in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to design my xslt in following logic. Please help m with it:

1. Count number of Items.
2. If position() is greater than split count, check if previous and current node value is same(MATNR in this case).
3. If value is same, do not break. Break only after value is different.
4. If value is different, break.
5. After break, start the counter again till split count is reached.

Example:
Split count=3

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Material>
  <Item><MATNR>22</MATNR></Item>
  <Item><MATNR>22</MATNR></Item>
  <Item><MATNR>24</MATNR></Item>
  <Item><MATNR>24</MATNR></Item>
  <Item><MATNR>25</MATNR></Item>
  <Item><MATNR>26</MATNR></Item>
  <Item><MATNR>27</MATNR></Item>
  <Item><MATNR>28</MATNR></Item>
  <Item><MATNR>29</MATNR></Item>
  <Item><MATNR>10</MATNR></Item>
</Material>
```

and output be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Material>
  <Item><MATNR>22</MATNR></Item>
  <Item><MATNR>22</MATNR></Item>
  <Item><MATNR>24</MATNR></Item>
  <Item><MATNR>24</MATNR></Item>
</Material>
<Material>
  <Item><MATNR>25</MATNR></Item>
  <Item><MATNR>26</MATNR></Item>
  <Item><MATNR>27</MATNR></Item>
</Material>
<Material>
  <Item><MATNR>28</MATNR></Item>
  <Item><MATNR>29</MATNR></Item>
  <Item><MATNR>10</MATNR></Item>
</Material>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How many of these items do you expect to have? This could easily overflow.

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is not "logic", it is a procedural algorithm. A procedural algorithm is not a good starting point for writing XSLT, because it's not a procedural language. A declarative description of your problem would be (I think):

Split the items into groups (preserving order) such that each group has the minimum number of items satisfying the constraints that (a) a group contains at least 3 items and (b) two items with the same MATNR always go in the same group.

So it's a grouping problem, which usually means that the solution for XSLT 2.0 is going to be a lot easier than the solution for 1.0. But in fact I think it's slightly beyond the capabilities of XSLT 2.0's xsl:for-each-group instruction.

That means you're going to have to use sibling recursion. You can find a number of examples of sibling recursion by searching StackOverflow: a good example to start with is this one:

[Grouping with no relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903210/grouping-with-no-relation/12926110#12926110)

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for your response. There is one more twist in current logic. If want to check sibling recursion only for last item in a group. As in example above, the first 2 items have same value but sibling recursion test is not needed at that position(break is not there). How do I check such conditions?

Comment: Your test for starting a new group is `current group size >=3 and current MATNR != previous MATNR`. So you just have to pass the required data in parameters to the recursive template to enable it to test that condition - specifically, pass the size of the current group and the value of the most recent MATNR.